# driver.quit() does not close all browser windows

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here's the code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

This opens two firefox windows.
In the @AfterMethod, I am calling

```
driver.quit();
```

In-spite of this, the first browser window does not close. I tried getting the windowhandles but only one window handle is returned. Is there anyway I can close both the broswer windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening two windows on purpose? If so, use 2 variables one for each window. Or, close the first window before creating a new window.

You are assigning a variable to a new FireFox window. Then you assign the same variable to a new window. You lost your connection to the first window because you stored the new window in the variable.

This would work:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
(...)
driver.quit();
driver2.quit();
```

This would work too:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
(...)
driver.quit();
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
(...)
driver.quit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I need two browser windows as I am testing a feature where an object locked by user1(browser1) is accessed by user2(browser2) and sees an error message as the object is locked by user1. I am opening the browser windows in the @BeforeMethod and hence would need the driver names to specified explicitly (driver and driver2). Let me see if I can modify the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening browser two times, with same object, apart from it if you want to use single object and if it opens two different web pages after doing some process then it will work, in case of your scenario, create two different object and one by one try to quit it, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your are creating a new instance of a browser and assigning it to the previous driver reference. Hence, calling driver.quit() will closes all windows related to the second instance but not the first one.To do this, you may instantiate two WebDriver references in two places if you need like this:

```
WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver2= new FirefoxDriver();
```

& call quit() method for two drivers:

```
driver1.quit();
driver2.quit();
```

**But if you need only one instance of it then avoid reassigning.**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was thinking of two driver instances might be the probable solution for this. However, I have the login method in the @BeforeMethod, so I do not have a control on the name of the driver instance created. Let me see if I can pass it as a parameter.